# how to test public void function which calls void private function of the same class using google test

Tags: c++, googletest

dummy code:

```
void fun()
{
    while (m->hasMessage())
    {
        std::pair<std::string, Vector> msg_pair = m->getMessage();
        auto topic = msg_pair.first;
        auto msg = msg_pair.second;

        for (auto const& x : msg)
        {
            auto const type = m->MessageType(x);

            if (type == "a")
            {
                funa(x,topic);
            }
            else if (type == "b")
            {
                funb(x,topic);
            }
            
            else if (type == "c")
            {
                func(x,topic);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

fun a,fun b , fun c are private functions and fun is public function of same class
how to test function fun using google test

Comment: what problem did you encounter? Why does it matter that the fucntion calls a private member?

Comment: I didnt faced any problem, I am searching a way to test above function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach that I have followed to test public function which in turn calling private function is adding `throw conditions(exceptions)` in private functions and in test case using macro `EXPECT_NOTHROW` to test the public function :

```
EXPECT_NOTHROW(obj.publicfunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not test private functions, only public interfaces

However,if you really need it you can use this (straight from Google Test docs...):

> FRIEND_TEST(TestCaseName, TestName);

For example

```
class MyClass {
  friend class MyClassTest;
  FRIEND_TEST(MyClassTest, HasPropertyA);
  FRIEND_TEST(MyClassTest, HasPropertyB);
  ... definition of class MyClass ...
};
```

Comment: I am not testing private function, i want to test public function (above dummy code) which in turn calls private function

Comment: Have you tried using the functior pattern with Google Mock? Exactly what do you want to test inside those private functions? That they are being called? Use google mock.

Comment: since private functions and public function is part of same class, how can one use google mock and call it using macro EXPECT_CALL where it takes two parameters mock object and function with parameter (where one needs to create MOCK_METHOD)

Comment: Sorry for repeating myself: you should only test public functions. If you really really want to test the call of private functions the only way is to use  the FRIEND_TEST() macro. Can you provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example with the description of what you want to test?